# Symfony2 Firewall rules are not working as expected

Tags: php, security, symfony, acl

I specify two rules in access control section of the security.yml config like this:

```
 - { path: ^/logout,      role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
 - { path: ^/admin,       role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

But in both cases user anonymous user can go to both pages, and in admin case in toolbar I can see like `anon.` comes to `admin` What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to define your firewall rules correctly, see [this article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html)

Comment: can you post the full security.yml file and include the firewall rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These rules look fine, the problem is probably in another part of your firewall configuration. Please post it.

The most likely is that you have another rule that matches these paths earlier in your rule list. For example, when you have

```
- { path: ^/,       role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

on top of your rule list, that will match all paths and the other rules will not get evaluated. In that case, make sure you move that rule to the end of your list.

If that is not the case, scan your firewall configuration for sections where you use `security: false` and take a look at the pattern.

Then there is also the *hit yourself on the head* scenario where you have your role hierarchy configured to let *ROLE_ADMIN* be inherited by anonymous users. But that is not the case right?

Also, note that when you define a path like `^/admin` that that also matches `^/administration` and all other paths that start with /admin. That might be fine to you, but when you want to make sure that you only exclude `/admin` and every subpath like `/admin/foo` having these two rules might fit your need better:

```
 - { path: ^/admin$,       role: ROLE_ADMIN }
 - { path: ^/admin/,       role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```